# Makefile : Clock skew detected

Tags: makefile, clock, skew

My problem is whenever I try to compile using Makefile I get the following :

```
make: Warning: File `Board.c' has modification time 1.3e+03 s in the future
gcc -Wall -c -Wvla -lm Board.c -o Board.o
gcc -Wall -c -Wvla -lm PlayBoard.c -o PlayBoard.o
gcc -lm ErrorHandle.o Board.o PlayBoard.o -g -o PlayBoard
make: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
```

My Makefile is :

```
CC = gcc
FLAGS = -Wall -c -Wvla

PlayBoard: ErrorHandle.o Board.o PlayBoard.o
    $(CC) -lm ErrorHandle.o Board.o PlayBoard.o -g -o $@

PlayBoard.o: PlayBoard.c Board.o
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -lm PlayBoard.c -o $@

Board.o : ErrorHandle.o Board.c Board.h
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -lm Board.c -o $@

.PHONY : clean

clean:
    rm -f Board.o PlayBoard.o PlayBoard

all : PlayBoard
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Check the modification time of `Board.c`, it appears that you may have copied this from another source when in the time of creation is ahead of your machin. One solution could be run `touch Board.c` to set the modification time to current time

Comment: are the sources stored on a network location perhaps?

Comment: This isn't related to C in any way. This is a warning issued by `make`.

Comment: @alk:  I can't see any tacit evidence that would warrant this question to be protected.  There aren't a lot of answers from low-rep members and there doesn't seem to be any immediate danger of this question being suddenly very popular and getting a lot of attention, either.

Answer (score 39):

A possible solution is to `touch` every file in the source tree in order to update time-stamps:

Go to the root of the sub-tree an do:

```
find . -exec touch {} \;
```

Then `make clean` and retry compilation.

Comment: Works every time. Thank you!

Comment: Doing so let's you then always and ever compile all an everything, not just only the source files which had been touched due to code changes. At least for a large code base this probably is not what you want,.

Answer (score 27):

As denoted in a comment by *stijn* the message "*Clock skew detected*" is most commonly given if compiling sources located on an NFS mount and the NFS server's clock runs ahead the client's clock doing the compilation.

Comment: Is there a solution to this?  My source files are on an nfs server that appears to be slightly ahead.  My dev machine and the nfs server are VM's on seperate domains so I may never get clocks exact

Comment: @Telium : You might want to run an N(erwork)T(ime)P(rotocol) client on both machines on a regular base?

Answer (score 3):

I saw this in Eclipse a couple of times as well when doing some work on one of the University computers here. My data drive was a network drive and the clock difference between the network drive and the local machine was off.

Switching my workspace to a location on the local machine (C drive) fixed the problem